# How to fix the size of 3 pictures in a table?

Tags: html, css, image

so I have this code in html and css and I am trying to make both 3 pictures in a same size and put the caption also in the middle of page and I am not really finding a soultion since I am a bit new to html and css and have stuggles sometime who ever can help thanks a lot. This is what I have.

```
<article>
    <aside>
        <caption>
            <strong>Photos of some most liked fast foods</strong>
        </caption>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>Hot Dog</th> 
                <th>Taco</th>
                <th>Donuts</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of a Hot Dog">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of Tacos">
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a href="https://www.eitanbernath.com/2020/05/01/chocolate-glazed-donuts-with-sprinkles/" target="_blank"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of Donuts"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</article>
    </aside>
```

```
#table1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table1 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
}
#table1 td, #table1 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Thanks for your time to everyone.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layout. Use CSS instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define width & height for the images and then you can use `object-fit: cover`. For centering the cell content you can use `text-align: center`.

By the way, you swaped the last two closing tags...

**Working example:**

```css
#table1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table1 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
}
#table1 td, #table1 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <aside>
        <caption>
            <strong>Photos of some most liked fast foods</strong>
        </caption>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>Hot Dog</th> 
                <th>Taco</th>
                <th>Donuts</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Photo of a Hot Dog">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Photo of Tacos">
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a href="https://www.eitanbernath.com/2020/05/01/chocolate-glazed-donuts-with-sprinkles/" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="Photo of Donuts"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </aside>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got a few problems you need to fix:

1. You're using `<table>` to do layout. Bad practice for search engines and your layout
2. `<caption>` goes inside `<table>`. Just for you to know as you'll remove your table anyway
3. You have your `</aside>` and `</article>` closing tags reversed. In most cases, browsers will fix that... Until some day they can't figure it out and you spend 4 hours looking for a bug.

So good practice would have you use one block for each picture. As they each have their own caption, I decided to use `<figure>` here which is for "self-contained content, potentially with an optional caption". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Then I set the figures side by side using a `grid` layout for their parent `<div class="pics">`. Another way to achieve that could have been `flex`. Choice between those is mostly a matter of fluid/responsive design and having to manage several rows.

Now we also have to manage the borders around and between the elements. To emulate the table feature `border-collapse`, I've set the left border to `none` for all figures except the first one using the `:not` and `:first-child` selectors combined.

```css
article {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.pics-pane h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.pics-pane .pics {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.pics-pane figure {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pics-pane figure:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: none;
}

.pics-pane figcaption {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pics-pane figcaption, .pics-pane .imgbox {
    padding: 8px;
}

.pics-pane .imgbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pics-pane img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <aside>
        <div class="pics-pane" id="pics-pane-1">
          <h4>Photos of some most liked fast foods</h4>
          <div class="pics">
            <figure class="photo">
              <figcaption>Hot Dog</figcaption>
              <a class="imgbox">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of a Hot Dog">
              </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
              <figcaption>Taco</figcaption>
              <a class="imgbox">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of a Hot Dog">
              </a>
            </figure>
            <figure class="photo">
              <figcaption>Donuts</figcaption>
              <a class="imgbox" href="https://www.eitanbernath.com/2020/05/01/chocolate-glazed-donuts-with-sprinkles/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Photo of Donuts">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</article>
```